# Motherboard stops (sometimes) to recognize the HD when transferring some files

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I'm having some problems with my new mobo Gigabyte **GA-AB350M-D3H** (1.0) and my old hard drive Western Digital model **WD5000AAKS-007AA0** (500 GB).

In specific scenarios of transfer files, the motherboard stops to recognize the HD. In my last motherboard, this HD was working normal, the problems started with my new motherboard.

What scenarios I detected this happens:

- Installing Quake Champions using Bethesta launcher
- Installing/updating some Blizzard games using Battle.net launcher

In the middle of the game install/update, the file transfer stops and the Windows stop to recognize the HD. When I restart my PC after that, the bios post takes forever and, when the Windows 10 starts, he not recognize the HD anymore. I need to turn off my PC and turn on again to motherboard find the HD again.

The curious details about the Quake Champions is that the problem occurred always after the almost same amount of download (540 MB).

I already used the application from WD to detect problems in HD, but the HD are perfect, no problems are found. I changed the HD cable twice. I try to use another SATA port too. The problem still happens.

I have two Samsung SSDs installed in the same PC, they are working perfect. To play Quake Champions, I needed to install the game in one of this SSDs.

I updated to F3 Bios version (the last one), but this not resolve my problem.

I create a ticket in the Gigabyte support site, but they not answer me yet. I never see this problem before and Google show few results about this.

Anyone have an idea what to do before returning the motherboard?

Comment: I would still supect the western digital hard drive as failing.  I would get a copy of mhdd or something that does low level scans of the disk.  SpinRite by grc.com, but that cost money.  It a highly recommend program.

Comment: @cybernard this software appears to be very good, thanks for the tip. I'm thinking in buy a new and bigger HD to replace the old one, but I will be disappointed if the problem still continue after that... but discover that the problem continue with a new motherboard would be worst :).

Comment: You said you have to SSD that work fine.  I seriously doubt its the motherboard.  I have had the issue on the hdd, where the motor on the hard drive is failing so after power save stops the motor, it won't wake up again.  Then I could reboot, but usually just unplug and re-plug the power cable from the back of the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments already, this could be the drive failing. Unexpected or unexplained intermittent access loss to the drive requiring measures such as rebooting is almost a sure sign of a drive that is *extremely close* to dying completely. And, depending on cause, this might not necessarily be detected by diagnostic software.

I would back up the WD HDD as soon as possible (or at least any important files). If the drive is failing, you won't be able to get that information back if it fails completely (which it will and possibly very soon).

As a small anecdote, I recently dealt with this twice in one year. One drive I was lucky on. I recognized the signs and made backups that allowed me to keep many important files. With another external backup drive, I thought it was a cable or driver issue and ignored the obvious and lost everything.

Comment: After few weeks with my new HD the problem not happens anymore. Thanks @cybernard and @Anaksunaman!